# Bootstrapping RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I have followed several tutorials on running an RMI application. However, I can't seem to make it work, as I keep getting stuck on the same error: `ClassNotFoundException`. I know that this error means that I have put my files in the wrong place but I tried to put `Client.class` everywhere and I had no success.

This is Bootstrap.java:

```
package mobility_server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public interface Bootstrap extends Remote  {
    Runnable getClient() throws RemoteException;
}
```

This is Client.java:

```
package mobility_server;
import java.io.*;

public class Client implements Runnable, Serializable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Io sono il Client caricato dinamicamente");
        try {
            System.out.println("ora scrivo su prova.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("prova.txt"));
            out.write("ciaociao");
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Ora leggo da prova.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("prova.txt"));
            String c = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(c);
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Policy:

```
grant {
    // Allow everything for now
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

This is BootstrapServer.java:

```
package mobility_server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*; 
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

class BootstrapServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Bootstrap {
    public BootstrapServer() throws RemoteException {}

    public Runnable getClient() {
        return new Client();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Bootstrap server = new BootstrapServer();
        System.out.println("Il Server di Bootstrap e' stato lanciato.");
        Naming.rebind("//:3333/BootServer",server);
        System.out.println("Il Server di Bootstrap e' stato registrato nel registro RMI.");
     }
}
```

This is RMIClientBootstrap.java:

```
package mobility_server;
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.rmi.*; 
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
//Bootstrap bootstrap = (Bootstrap) Naming.lookup("//157.127.135.126:3333/BootServer");

public class RMIClientBootstrap {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Il client si accinge a fare la lookup");
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            try {
                String host = args[i];
                int  port = Registry.REGISTRY_PORT;
                if (i+1 < args.length) {
                    try {
                        port = Integer.parseInt(args[i + 1]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // next arg isn't a port number
                    }
                }
                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host,port);
                // if the try construct failed we have in the variable port
                //the standard port number 1099 from Registry.REGISTRY_PORT
                System.out.println("Contenuto del registro RMI presso "+host+":"+port);
                String list[] = registry.list();
                Bootstrap bootstrap = (Bootstrap)registry.lookup(list[0]);
                // remember that the lookup method return a remote reference, that is a stub.
                System.out.println(".\tnome="+list[0]+"\n\tstub="+bootstrap);

                System.out.println("Il client si accinge ad invocare il metodo getClient() del server ricavato dal registroRMI.");
                Runnable client = bootstrap.getClient();
                System.out.println("Il client ha ottenuto un'istanza della classe Client e la lancia");
                client.run(); 
            }//TRY
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                System.out.println("SONO NEL CATCH " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }//FOR
    }
}
```

And I've made these two script:

Server.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

rmi=$(pidof "rmiregistry")

if [ `pidof "rmiregistry" | cut -d" " -f1` ]; then
    kill -9 $rmi
fi

cd ~/javarmi/mobility_server/
javac Bootstrap.java Client.java BootstrapServer.java

cp Client.class ~/public_html/common/mobility_server/
rm Client.class

cd ~/javarmi/
rmic -d ~/public_html/common/ mobility_server.BootstrapServer

cd ~/javarmi/
unset CLASSPATH
rmiregistry 3333 -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://192.168.1.68/public_html/common/ &

cd ~/javarmi/
java -Djava.security.policy=/home/emanuele/javarmi/mobility_server/policy -              Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://192.168.1.68/public_html/common/        mobility_server.BootstrapServer
```

Client.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/javarmi/mobility_server/
javac Bootstrap.java RMIClientBootstrap.java

cd ~/javarmi/
java -Djava.security.policy=/home/emanuele/javarmi/mobility_server/policy         mobility_server.RMIClientBootstrap 192.168.1.68 3333
```

Comment: Why are you removing Client.class?

Comment: Java try to load classes from files on CLASSPATH. What is your setting of CLASSPATH and where do you place 'Client.class' files? You unset CLASSPATH in 'Server.sh', when do you set CLASSPATH again??  I suspect that 'unset CLASSPATH' makes your trouble.

Comment: Honestly, in 99% of real RMI code, remote classloaders are not used.  ditch the classloader, securitymanager and the server codebase and just make sure you add the client classes to the client classpaths (the registry and your Client).

Answer (score 2):

What a strange mess. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash    
rmi=$(pidof "rmiregistry")    
if [ `pidof "rmiregistry" | cut -d" " -f1` ]; then
    kill -9 $rmi
fi  

cd ~/javarmi
javac mobility_server/Bootstrap.java mobility_server/Client.java mobility_server/BootstrapServer.java
rmic mobility_server.BootstrapServer
cp mobility_server/Client.class mobility_server/BootstrapServer_Stub.class ~/public_html/common/mobility_server/

(unset CLASSPATH; cd /; rmiregistry 3333)&

java -Djava.security.policy=/home/emanuele/javarmi/mobility_server/policy -              Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://192.168.1.68/public_html/common/        mobility_server.BootstrapServer
```

Specifically:

1. You're removing Client.class from the very place that your BootstrapServer will look for it.
2. Similarly you aren't putting the stub class where the server will look for it.
3. You're incorrectly setting the codebase property on the Registry JVM when you only need to set it on the server JVM.

Comment: I tried again with your code, although I have changed your cp with      cp ~/javarmi/mobility_server/Client.class    ~/javarmi/mobility_server/BootstrapServer_Stub.class    ~/public_html/common/mobility_server/      And this is my error

Comment: Il client si accinge a fare la lookup
Contenuto del registro RMI presso 157.27.241.240:3333
. nome=BootServer
 stub=BootstrapServer_Stub[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[157.27.241.240:36626](remote),objID:[-52231382:14ac9ea0026:-7fff, -8491219367150469759]]]]
Il client si accinge ad invocare il metodo getClient() del server ricavato dal registroRMI.
SONO NEL CATCH error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mobility_server.Client
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:....

Comment: You need to start the Registry from a different directory so it won't find the classes via the automatic `.` CLASSPATH. Otherwise you lose the codebase annotation on classes that go through it.